# Is the coefficient of the series $-\frac{x}{2}\cot(\pi)= $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, riemann-zeta

Is the coefficient of the series $-\frac{x}{2}\cot(\pi x)= \zeta(2n)=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}B_{2n}2^{2n}(\pi )^{2n}}{2(2n)!}$

The Maclaurin series formula for $\cot(x)$ is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}B_{2n}2^{2n}x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$

$$-\dfrac{x}{2}\cot(\pi x)= \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}B_{2n}2^{2n}(\pi x)^{2n-1}}{2(2n)!}$$

If this is so, why does wiki gave the generating function:

"The values of the zeta function at non-negative even integers have the generating function:"

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\zeta(2n)x^{2n}=\dfrac{\pi x}{2}\cot(\pi x)=-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}x^2+\dfrac{\pi^4}{90}x^4+\dfrac{\pi^6}{945}x^6...$$

Why do we need an extra $\pi$

Wiki proof also employ the function $-\pi x\cot(\pi x)$ for its proof:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann_Zeta_Function_at_Even_Integers

Why not use this function, which is easier. In fact, after deriving the formula for Maclaurin series of $\cot(x)$, I have come up with this function, but I thought I was wrong.

Comment: Why do we need an extra pie ? ... Just in case someone else comes around for Dinner! ... Which $\pi$ do you consider to be "extra" ?

Comment: OK, sorry all, I get one problem $x^{2n-1}$ in the the series of $\cot(x)$, not $x^{2n}$, I am so dumb. No more questions. Just one last question, why do we need $\pi x\cot(\pi x)$ in wiki proof and not $\dfrac{x\pi}{2}\cot(\pi x)$

Comment: Man, I am filled with joy for finally derive the generating function by myself, I thought I was wrong.